# Convert "words" of an int64 into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, int64

I have this variable:

print(mv)

```
genus                4505 
snails                386 
level                 460 
cats                 2813
```

Please note that this is a siplification of an array of 100*1000 cells.

The origin of this variable is:

> mv = miss_values_count[miss_values_count != 0]

and its type is int64

I want to make a list with the names and without the numbers...

LIke this:

> [genus, snails, level, cats]

I have tried this

```
list=[mv[0],mv[1],mv[2],mv[3]]
```

but the output has the numbers...

What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, is that `mv` a Pandas DataFrame or something? I think you're misunderstanding your data types, the second column is likely represented in `int64` not your dataframe `mv` itself

Comment: Can you show us what `print(type(mv), type(miss_values_count))` gives?

Answer (score 0):

To get the the list of indices of a `pd.Series`:

```
lst = list(mv.index)
```

Comment: It sent me an error: IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: I just realized that is not a pd.Series

Comment: You yourself wrote this error raised from @captainK 's post: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`. So according to this the datatype is Series. I don't understand how could it not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you constructed your pandas Dataframe as follows

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> mv = pd.DataFrame([['genus', 4505],
                       ['snails', 386],
                       ['level', 460],
                       ['cats', 2813]],
                      columns=['name', 'number'])
```

Then you can get the `'names'` column as follows

```
>>> mv['name']
0     genus
1    snails
2     level
3      cats
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: I Haven't  constructed this, is not a 4*2 array, it has 100*1000. The post is a simplification.

Comment: @JoanSerrano I am showing the general idea to index a particular column of a dataframe. If you want a more specific answer, you need to update your post to include more details

Answer (score -1):

If the numbers are always going to be positive integers then following will work:

```
text = 'genus 4505 snails 386 level 460 cats 2813'
list = [x for x in text.split(' ') if not x.isdigit()]
print(list)

['genus', 'snails', 'level', 'cats']
```

The reason I mentioned positive integers is because isdigit doesn't work with negative integers.

Update: Before the question was edited, it looked like the input was a string, hence my answer as above.

Update2: It is a Pandas Dataframe. You need to use the column name. Here is my dataframe. col1 and col2 are header columns.

```
col1    col2 
genus   4505
snails   386
level    460
cats    2813
```

This will give me values of col1 in list:

```
list = df['col1'].tolist()
```

Comment: Hence the 'Update' section in my answer.

Comment: It sent me this error: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @JoanSerrano: Added an Update2 in my answer.